# namenode -format delete files in hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I uploaded data successfully from mysql to HDFS by sqoop command.

MySQL Hadoop Cluster have

1 Node for Namename
1 Node for Secondary NameNode
1 Node for Jobtracker
3 Nodes for Datanade + Tasktracker

After that I stopped the hadoop cluster.

And again to start Hadoop

Used below command

```
  namenode -format (start NameNode)

  place new VERSION number in all datanode VERSION FILE

  now START DATANODE
```

While starting datanode my upload MYSQL Data  in HDFS seems to be lost.

Below is the output from the datanode logs.

```
2014-05-15 07:46:56,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_2445513848423894029_1337 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_2445513848423894029
2014-05-15 07:46:56,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_3541234094053021888_1338 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_3541234094053021888
2014-05-15 07:46:56,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_3862391472172526583_1347 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_3862391472172526583
2014-05-15 07:46:56,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_4001223662527683746_1387 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_4001223662527683746
2014-05-15 07:46:56,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_4143551839757190038_1410 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/subdir14/blk_4143551839757190038
2014-05-15 07:46:56,019 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_5292612097544035620_1384 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_5292612097544035620
2014-05-15 07:46:56,019 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_5318982235915332439_1333 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_5318982235915332439
2014-05-15 07:46:56,019 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_5806860765395122737_1388 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_5806860765395122737
2014-05-15 07:46:56,019 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_6490571696460682483_1302 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_6490571696460682483
2014-05-15 07:46:56,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_7721528058087862562_1336 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_7721528058087862562
2014-05-15 07:46:56,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_7734832800955956873_1375 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_7734832800955956873
2014-05-15 07:46:56,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_8691928504867292802_1297 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_8691928504867292802
2014-05-15 07:46:56,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_8861743153245195509_1303 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_8861743153245195509
2014-05-15 07:46:56,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_8921828525927242630_1300 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_8921828525927242630
2014-05-15 07:46:56,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Deleted blk_8938258584084219299_1344 at file
```

Comment: Please state a **specific question** so users know exactly what you want help with.

Comment: what do your want......please add more info about your error

Comment: What is the third step exactly? "place new VERSION number in all datanode VERSION FILE"?

Comment: When I changed new VERSION of namenode to all datanode . and started datanodes , all uploaded data is deleted with below error               Deleted blk_6490571696460682483_1302 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_6490571696460682483                           My Question is when we use Haddop fs -format command is all data formatted , Is there way to recover data

Answer (score 0):

My Question as below

When I changed new VERSION of namenode to all datanode . and started datanodes , all uploaded RDBMS data is deleted with below error in log file "Deleted blk_6490571696460682483_1302 at file /app/hadoop/data/dn/current/blk_6490571696460682483"

My Question is when we use Haddop fs -format command is all data formatted , Is there way to recover data

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional info and do not use this section for comments.

Comment: add more info in original Question